# Enabling stream management to use it in smack android application openfire v4.7.3

Tags: java, android, openfire, smack

I encountered an issue where messages are not delivered when the Wi-Fi or cellular data is turned off on an Android device. Even after re-enabling the network connection, the messages remain undelivered. How can I address this situation in the code using Openfire and Smack?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please note that Openfire 4.7.3 has an important security issue. I strongly recommend that you upgrade to 4.7.5 or later. Please refer to https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/cve-2023-32315-openfire-vulnerability-update for details on the security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Both Smack and Openfire support the Stream Management feature (as defined in [XEP-0198: Stream Management](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html)).

In Smack, you can enable it using this method:

```java
XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
connection.setUseStreamManagement(true);
```

However, I believe that, by default, this already is enabled.